# RGBDSLAM customization

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, 3dslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have RGBDSLAM installed on Ubuntu 14.04 via ROS Indigo (virtualBox via osx el captian). I have everything working well and I'd like to start adding custom functionality. I have a lot of experience with coding but I don't have much experience with ROS or RGBDSLAM. How can I add custom functionality to RGBDSLAM?

I would like to accomplish:

- [object detection](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/correspondence_grouping.php)
- [human detection](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/ground_based_rgbd_people_detection.php#ground-based-rgbd-people-detection)
- send data (rgbd, octomap, and/or point clouds) to separate machine for in-depth processing

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get started?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226320/rgbdslam-customization/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general, decoupling and modularization is one of the main ideas of ROS. Therefore for most things you will want to create your own nodes that subscribe to the topics advertised by rgbdslam (while it is running, you can check them out in rqt_graph or via `rosnode info <name-of-rgbdslam-node>`). You can also call rgbdslam's services from your node, e.g., to make it send out data or save the octomap. See `rosservice list` and rgbdslam's readme.

If you need other functionality or data, you might implement another service call or topic in rgbdslam and process it in an external node. As an example, you might have a look at the feature-msg-output branch on github, where I implemented sending out of the extracted features.

For processing the clouds as a map, you could subscribe to the openni driver and the /tf frames from rgbdslam, assemble the clouds according to the received transformation and then run the pcl code on it.

Sending data to other machines can be done by ROS (more or less) [out-of-the-box.](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup)

If you want to work on pointclouds within rgbdslam, probably the best place would be to call your code from the end of [GraphManager::optimizeGraphImpl](https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2/blob/feature-msg-output/src/graph_manager.cpp#L939). Your code will then run after graph optimization, i.e., when the refined trajectory estimation has taken place. Note that also in this case, you will need to merge the individual clouds. Check out  [GraphManager::saveAllClouds](https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2/blob/feature-msg-output/src/graph_mgr_io.cpp#L501) for an example of how to do it.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2016-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1